# create react app production build behaves different than dev

Tags: create-react-app, relay

I've a create-react-app which is running fine started with yarn start
Creating the production build works without any error as well, but running the production build results in errors in multiple places of the app.
The errors are all related to graphql relay queries returning (the same queries with identical results from the same backend work in development)

Is there any good way to debug it? Currently the thrown errors basically give me very limited information.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem:

I had a few files copied form another project which used

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

exports.default = DeselectAllButton;
```

The development server was just working fine, but the production build resulted in very strange errors hidden in react.
Replacing the exports resolved the issue